# AngularJS Controller Error - TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to load data from json. But my code is error. How can I fix it?

**error message**

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (http://s.codepen.io/boomerang/f0c70f5befd13788970cee6187a271461412729151639/index.html:66:15)
    at invoke (http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.6/js/ionic.bundle.js:12639:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.6/js/ionic.bundle.js:12650:23)
    at http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.6/js/ionic.bundle.js:15709:28
    at http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.6/js/ionic.bundle.js:15118:34
    at forEach (http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.6/js/ionic.bundle.js:9239:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.6/js/ionic.bundle.js:15105:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.6/js/ionic.bundle.js:14569:15)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.6/js/ionic.bundle.js:14572:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.6/js/ionic.bundle.js:14474:30)
```

**JS file**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.factory('JsonService', function($http) {

  var url="http://www.garsoncepte.com/json.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

  var getData = function(successFn, errorFn){
    $http.get('url')
    .success(successFn)
    .error(errorFn);
  };

  return getData;
 })

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, JsonService) {
  JsonService.getData(function(data){ //It may be error code
    $scope.items = data;
  },function(error){});

});
```

I use this : http://codepen.io/m_abdelfattah/pen/Gkiju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', [])
.factory('JsonService', function($http) {
  var url="http://www.garsoncepte.com/json.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
  var getData = function(){
    return $http.get(url);
  };
  return {getData: getData};
 })

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, JsonService) {
  JsonService.getData()
  .success(function(data){
    $scope.items = data;
  })
  .error(function(){});
});
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mjx423tt/)

Comment: Thank you!! But I change url, I got another error.

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/xml: "myURL". ionic.bundle.js:17002
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : notice:1

What should I do?

Comment: @Berry That is a completely different issue. As you can see in the example of my answer: the code that I've provided you works perfectly fine. However, I have noticed that that URL: "http://www.garsoncepte.com/json.php?..." is not retrieving valid json data, because the JSON data comes wrapped as the parameter of a function defined you your "callback" query string. So that is a completely different issue. I will be happy to look into that other issue if you open a new question, but please accept this answer because it does fix the problem of the original question. Thanks!